# Intro to machine learning naive bayes classifier return statement

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I try to learn machine learning from Udacity's Intro to machine learning course.

Lesson 2- Naive Bayes quiz 19: Gaussian NB Deployment on Terrain Data

I have to add some code in the classifyNB.py file which I have added

```
def classify(features_train, labels_train):   
### import the sklearn module for GaussianNB
### create classifier
### fit the classifier on the training features and labels
### return the fit classifier


### your code goes here!
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
return((features_train, labels_train)
```

But the code did not compile and threw some errors.

Any idea what should I write in order to `return the fit classifier`

Comment: Try this: `return clf`

Comment: I write like that `return(clf)`. I suppose to get a picture because there are other .py files. This time after adding return(clf) I neither get error nor get any output.

Comment: Thanks Vaziri. After 2 mins of waiting I got the result. Thank you.

Comment: Did you indent the function body by 1 tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same exercise this way

```
def classify(features_train, labels_train):

### import the sklearn module for GaussianNB
### create classifier
### fit the classifier on the training features and labels
### return the fit classifier


### your code goes here!

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
return clf
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your code like this:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

def classify(features_train, labels_train):   
  clf = GaussianNB()
  clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
  return clf
```

Imports for modules should be outside of methods and you need to ensure, that you have proper indentation when writing a method. If your indentation in your code is the same as on here, then you need to indent the code inside your method, so that it's clear, that the lines below your method belong to that method.

Now, you can call your `classify()` method with some data to get the classifier, for instance like this:

```
clf = classify(np.array([[0,1,2],[1,1,1]]), [0,1])
```

And then you can use your classifier, which can be accessed by using `clf`

Answer (score -2):

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

def classify(features_train, labels_train):
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
return clf

Comment: PS:- We can write import inside definition of the function

Comment: Please do not duplicate answers

Comment: @proko actually it's my first answer I just wanted to state that even If we import in the method it doesn't cause any error .I thought best way would be mentioning the pervious ans